# Mysql choose to join table where record exists

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that are the same, but only in one of them a record exists and I need to choose which table to join.

Example:

Table **catalog**:

```
| catalog_id | catalog_name |
```

Table **catalog_draft**:

```
| catalog_id | catalog_name |
```

Table **catalog_items**:

```
| item_id | catalog_id | item_name |
```

So by this small example I need to get all items with catalog name, but catalog name could be in **catalog** or **catalog_draft** table.

Comment: I would suggest to rephrase the question to make sense. Assuming you would like to get some meaningful answer...

Comment: please add some more information (and examples, if possible). what have you tried yourself? what does the table-structure look like? it's hard to answer this with such little information you've given...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it myself by using IF. The solution query is:

```
SELECT 
   ci.item_name, ci.item_id, IF(c.catalog_name, c.catalog_name, cd.catalog_name)
FROM catalog_items AS ci
   LEFT JOIN catalog AS c
   ON c.catalog_id = ci.catalog_id
   LEFT JOIN catalog_draft AS cd
   ON cd.catalog_id = ci.catalog_id
```

Answer (score 3):

[Use union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
select something from table1 where id=?
union
select something from table2 where id=?;

example : 

mysql> select 1 union select 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

As for your *actual question*

```
select catalog_id, catalog_name from catalog where catalog_name=?
union
select catalog_id, catalog_name from catalog_draft where catalog_name=?;
```

The above union will combine result from two table.
That's mean if the catalog exist in catalog table and catalog_draft table,
only the first catalog is return from catalog table

Comment: Just to add to ajreal's answer:  By using Union it essentially performs two queries and returns both results combined.  Because only one table has the value, only the record from that table will be returned.   If for some reason both tables will have records then you need to either have the desired table be the first statment or sort the results by a field.....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. Let me see if I have got it right:

You have two tables `A` and `B`, both having the same columns. You have a certain row that exists in one of them. You want to find that table and join it with some other table?

If that is true, this is your answer:

Let's say the tables have these columns `(id, data)`

Here's how you can do it. For each table, you `outer join` the table with itself, select all rows that have the first part equal to what you are looking for, but select only the other columns. Then you union what you have done for both tables:

```
(SELECT * FROM
    A AS first RIGHT JOIN A AS second
    ON first.id = your_id AND first.data = your_data)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM
    B AS first RIGHT JOIN B AS second
    ON first.id = your_id AND first.data = your_data)
```

This way, the table that doesn't have the entry will have its `SELECT` return an empty table `UNION`ed with the complete other table.

Here's an example:

Data of table A

```
(0, 8324)
(1, 215)
(2, 47879)
```

When you outer join (full outer join), you get this:

```
(0, 8324, 0, 8324)
(0, 8324, 1, 215)
(0, 8324, 2, 47879)
(1, 215, 0, 8324)
(1, 215, 1, 215)
(1, 215, 2, 47879)
(2, 47879, 0, 8324)
(2, 47879, 1, 215)
(2, 47879, 2, 47879)
```

When you outer join on `first.id == 1 AND first.data == 215` you get:

```
(1, 215, 0, 8324)
(1, 215, 1, 215)
(1, 215, 2, 47879)
```

Now if you have `right join`ed instead of full join, you would get:

```
(0, 8324)
(1, 215)
(2, 47879)
```

There you have table A! If you were searching for an entry that didn't exist, you would have got an empty table.

In the end, the result of this command is a table you could use elsewhere, for example if you want to join it with some other table:

```
SELECT * FROM
    ((SELECT * FROM
        A AS first RIGHT JOIN A AS second
        ON first.id = your_id AND first.data = your_data)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM
        B AS first RIGHT JOIN B AS second
        ON first.id = your_id AND first.data = your_data))
    JOIN other_table ON some_condition
```

Comment: After OP edited his question, turned out he meant something simpler. If you think I should delete this answer, write a comment and I'll delete it.